# vs2013 dark theme annoying line

Tags: visual-studio-2013, themes

I recently installed vs2013 and am using the dark theme.
on the left side I have that broken annoying line.

(I cant post an image cause don't have enough reputation but you can view it here - https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcB9B.png)

Do you know how I can get rid of this line?
Thanks

Comment: If you down vote at least leave a comment to indicate why are you doing so, so I could at least learn from my mistakes

Comment: Right click in the editor on the same column as the guideline and in the menu, select the guideline > remove guideline option.  Though this is just one way since there are different extensions with different guideline implementations.

Comment: Perfect! it works! I would have accepted it as an answer but not sure how to do it as you answered in a comment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per David Ruhmann's comment -

> Right click in the editor on the same column as the guideline and in the menu, select the guideline > remove guideline option

Thanks